How is rating calculated for players who haven't played for long time (e.g. decades)?
Once in my life, I participated in a Canada Chess Federation (CFC) rated tournament, and that's how I obtained my initial (and the one and only) rating. That was more than 20 years ago though, and I haven't played since.
Recently, I started considering playing in another CFC rated tournament again.
I thought I am no longer in their database, but apparently I still am, and my rating remains the same as it was back then since that tournament.
I sent an inquiry to find out what my actual rating is now, but they never replied.
So I am curious as to if there's any rules/formula for calculating ratings for inactive players?
Thanks

According to the 2014 CFC handbook (emphasis mine):


Current Ratings: All events are normally rated in chronological order with the current ratings from CFC files. When an event is rated, the ratings produced become the new current ratings and are used for the next calculations. The ratings of players who are inactive are still valid, except that the ratings of players rated under 1400 are cancelled after 5 years of inactivity.


There is an indication on the CFC website that "Although it is no longer the 'official' CFC Bylaws nor is it legally binding, Vlad Drkulec, the current CFC president, has promised to abide by the legacy CFC Handbook as CFC policy to the extent possible consistent with the NFP Act." So, as far as I know, this rule is still in effect.
FIDE ratings are not ever cancelled due to inactivity, nor are USCF ratings.

Thank you for clarification.
Although, in the lights of this, my willingness to participate dropped a bit as I'll prob end up continusly facing much stronger opponents until I actually get a chance to play with somebody of my level. By then though, the tournament might be over.

@timbits Does the rating mean you can't play in the lower section? If so, I'll point out that if you did lose a lot, your rating would change quickly (it's not an "established" rating since, regardless of its age, it's still based on only a few games) so you'd likely be able to play in a more appropriate section in the next tournament.

Yes, due to my rating (i.e. ~2100), I can't play in a lower section. Ironically, based on the participants who already registered for that tournament, I would be the highest rated player there (if I were to register). Realistically though, my current rating is way lower i.e. prob somewhere within 1800-1900 range, based on my performance on chess.com.
